# Ubuntu 16.04: Dual monitor will not change resolution

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors

On startup, my second monitor displays at a resolution of 1920 x 1080 16:9. However, this does not fit my screen properly.

I go to system settings -> display, to change the resolution of my dual monitor. After doing so, the monitor loses the connection and no longer displays anything. When I toggle different resolutions and hit apply, my dual monitor will show a black screen for a half-second and go back to no signal.

My computer seems to think that there is a connection because I can slide my cursor past the right edge of my first monitor.

Even when I click the 'restore previous configuration' button, the signal doesn't come back. The only way I can get the dual monitor to display anything is to reboot.

My second monitor is a 55" Samsung LED TV.

Processor: Intel COre i7 CPU 940 @ 2.93GHz × 8 
Graphics: NV92
OS type: 64-bit

edit: I somehow fixed this issue but I'm not sure why it worked.

This is what happened:

1. Change monitor resolution to 1600x900, click 'apply'
2. Dual monitor loses connection.
3. click "keep configuration"
4. Change monitor resolution to 1920 x 1080 16:9, click 'apply'
5. click "keep configuration"
6. Screen still has no connection
7. Toggle the second monitor from 'on' to 'off', click 'apply'
8. Hit 'restore to previous configuration'
9. The monitor shows the display again in 1920 x 1080 16:9
10. Change resolution to 1600x900
11. For whatever reason, this time the resolution changes without losing the signal.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow fixed this issue but I'm not sure why it worked.

This is what happened:

1) Change monitor resolution to 1600x900, click 'apply'

2) Dual monitor loses connection.

3) click "keep configuration"

4) Change monitor resolution to 1920 x 1080 16:9, click 'apply'

5) click "keep configuration"

6) Screen still has no connection

7) Toggle the second monitor from 'on' to 'off', click 'apply'

8) Hit 'restore to previous configuration'

9) The monitor shows the display again in 1920 x 1080 16:9

10) Change resolution to 1600x900

For whatever reason, this time the resolution changes without losing the signal. I think step 7 and 8 is what fixed it.